# Multiple Threads, one at a time read/write 

Tags: c++, qt

There are two `QFile-pointer` pointing to the same file, they belong different threads. One writes data to the file, the other reads. But I want to have only one operation going on, read or write.

```
if(!this->file->exists()) {
   qDebug()<<"The file is not exists";
}
if(this->file->isOpen()) {
   qDebug()<<"The file is open";
}
```

Let me put it another way: how to check whether the file in opened?

I test `file.isOpen()`? It doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language. Please remove the `c` tag since this is C++.

Comment: `file.is_open ()` is correct syntax

Comment: is QFile pointer thread safe? Else used a scoped lock (on a mutex).

Comment: @CodingMash: No, [`isOpen`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#isOpen) is the correct function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like to me you're trying to use isOpen to see if another thread has the same file open. AFAIK isOpen just tells you if the current QFile instance has a file open, not other QFile instances.

The only way I'm aware of being able to prevent different threads from reading and/or writing the same file is with file locking.

Not too sure if Qt has a way of doing this without having to delve into the more OS dependent APIs.